# Install latest PHP version

Tags: php, nginx

I want to be free to choose what ever PHP version (could works as fastcgi with Nginx) so I have tried procedures indicated in [this official article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.nginx.php). However, I got the following error when trying to `cp php.ini-development /usr/local/php/php.ini`

> cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/php/php.ini': No such file
> or directory

So I need to know the suitable procedures for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please do `sudo cp php.ini-development /usr/local/php/php.ini`, you need to do that as root. And Ubuntu has the nginx package, also latest php which can be installed using `apt`

Comment: It is `sudo` before, i.e `sudo -s` and also I tried it with `siudo`

Comment: Why don't create those folders but of course first check if they exist!

Comment: @George good hint. However, `sudo nautilus ` does not work. I will try to solve this issue.

Comment: Don't `sudo nautilus`, do `sudo mkdir /usr/local/php` from the terminal which you can open with `ctrl + alt + t`

Answer (score 3):

If You didn't get Your php as Ubuntu package You may need repository for the latest php version:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

Then follow the package You are interested in, for example:

`sudo apt-get install php7.1`

Remember to use `sudo` when needed as George suggested.

Comment: I don't prefer to use extra repositories, specially, when I don't know its origin. However, it is good solution if there is nothing else it.